# Is it okay to use the same layout for two different activities?

Tags: android, performance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
    android:text="Start Download" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Both activities have to perform the same things.The only difference is the type of data they handles.
Just for curiosity I am asking this question.

Comment: yes you  can use same layout for multiple time and its good for  your  app size

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's no problem with that technically.  Just remember that if you change anything for one activity it will change for both, so its best suited for very simple layouts.  But frequently I'll use the same placeholder for 4 or 5 activities that aren't written yet, or I'll use the same layout for placeholder listview elements.

Comment: Also if you have an `onClick` tag in your xml layout, you have to make sure to implement the method in both activities or your app will crash as soon as the activity thats missing the method is created